# How to convert a list of numpy arrays with empty arrays into a single array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So my data looks like:

```
[array([0], dtype=int64),
 array([1], dtype=int64),
 array([1], dtype=int64),
 array([2], dtype=int64),
 array([3], dtype=int64),
 array([3], dtype=int64),
 array([4], dtype=int64),
 array([], dtype=int64),
 array([], dtype=int64),
 array([], dtype=int64),
 array([], dtype=int64),
 array([], dtype=int64),
 array([], dtype=int64),
 array([], dtype=int64),
 array([], dtype=int64),
 array([], dtype=int64),
 array([], dtype=int64),
 array([], dtype=int64),
 array([], dtype=int64),
 array([], dtype=int64),
 array([6], dtype=int64) ...
```

While using `np.concatenate(list_1)` does concatenate the arrays but skips the empty arrays. And in tthe resultant array 6 is the next element to 4 and intermediate empty arrays does not appear in the list. This is what np.concateneate does but I do not want it that way.

**I want to combine those arrays into a single array having same length as the list but `NaN` values in place of empty arrays.** How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way:

```
np.concatenate([a if a.size else np.array([np.nan]) for a in array_list])
```

I would hazard a guess though there is probably a better way to load your data.

As a side note, `concatenate` does not skip any array - it concatenates the arrays, that is, puts the elements for each one after the other. Placing 0 elements is just not noticeable.

Comment: This is likely a very good way. You have to flag your missing items somehow one way or another

Comment: There been some errors. I was able to run your snippet with following changes: `np.concatenate([a if a.size else np.asarray([np.nan]) for a in array_list])`

Comment: @User5 np.array is enough though it shouldn't matter. I indeed had spelling mistakes (forgot `size` is not a function), thanks.

Comment: Thanks! @kabanus that worked though and I cannot think of a better way to do it!

Answer (score 0):

You can pre-allocate the output and assign to it directly:

```
result = np.full(len(list_1), np.nan)
for i, v in enumerate(list_1):
    if v.size:
        result[i] = v.item()
```

Alternatively, you can do

```
result = np.empty(len(list_1))
for i, v in enumerate(list_1):
    result[i] = v.item() if v.size else np.nan
```